# php highlight search keywords [working solution]!

Tags: php

I just spent the whole night writing this little script for my search engine. Now i want to improve it.

Any ideas?

```
<?php 
echo "KEYWORDS : ".  $searchstring  = "the and";

$sentence = "Skype Home is unavailable at the moment. Check back later to see your news and alerts.  It's easy to start a conversation on Skype:  Choose a contact and start talking Call a phone or mobile from the dial pad, or send an SMS.";

echo "<br><br><b>ORIGINAL STRING</b><br><br>$sentence";


$kt=split(' ',$searchstring); //Breaking the string to array of words

$num=1;

while(list($key,$val)=each($kt)){
    // do not load sentence from session on first run!  

    if($num<=1){
    } else {
        $sentence  = $_SESSION['NewSentence'];
    }
    if($val<>" " and strlen($val) > 0){

        // make keyword bold and send entire sentence to session

        $_SESSION['NewSentence']    = eregi_replace ("$val", "<b>$val</b>", $sentence);
        // output sentence with added keyword

        echo "<br><br>$num bolding:  <b style='color:green;'>$val</b> <br><br>  ".$_SESSION['NewSentence'];

        $num++;
    }
}

// make all bold keywords to red`

echo '<br><br><b>FINAL STRING</b><br><br>';
echo  $_SESSION['NewSentence'] = eregi_replace ("<b>", "<b style='color:red'>", $_SESSION['NewSentence']);

//destroy  session
unset($_SESSION['NewSentence']);
session_unregister($_SESSION['NewSentence']);?>
```

Answer (score 5):

## Use of deprecated functions

Both `split()` and `eregi_replace()` are deprecated since PHP 5.3. Don't use them.

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead of `eregi_replace()` and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) instead of `split()` Other alternatives are [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

## Unexpected results

When the search string is lowercase, all replaced words will be lowercase too. The case of the original word is not preserved.

## Unused variables

The `$key` variable is assigned but never used. In fact, the entire `while` loop is odd. Use a `foreach` loop instead, like so:

```
foreach($kt as $val) {
    ...
```

### Missing function

The code should be in a function. The function would require two parameters, the string and an array of words to highlight, and return the result string. The function should not echo anything (but I presume the echo statements are debugging things).

### Old HTML

Although valid, the use of `<b>` tags is outdated. It describes formatting in a document layout, without specifying the need for the format. You should use html for layout and css for styling. Then you can replace the `<b>` with a `<span class="highlight>` (or any other sensible class name).

Answer (score 3):

## Unused if statements

You have a `if($num<=1)` statment that is empty, while your using `else`. Reverse the statement like this.

```
if ($num > 1) {
    $sentence  = $_SESSION['NewSentence'];
}
```

## Ambiguous use of $_SESSION

You should not use `$_SESSION` as a storage unless you are going to use it in another session (read: new page load/refresh). At the end of your script you're destroying the session, if that's your intention use variables as placeholders and leave `$_SESSION` alone.

## Hard to read code

You should always aim to make the code as readable as possible. Take for example look at [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) and [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) to learn a coding *standard*.